# Чтение из файла в список

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

У меня текстовый файл, в котором уже сохранен список.

```
pairs.txt           [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Необходимо точно такой же список открыть в `python`, чтобы работать с ним, например проходить его циклом, и так далее.

Этот метод превращает все в строку.

```
with open('pairs.txt', 'r') as text:
    mylist = text.read()
```

Этот метод делает из содержимого файла новый список, поглотив старый, с одним элементом внутри вместо 5. Как избавиться от общего списка?

```
with open('pairs.txt', 'r') as text:
    mylist = text.readlines()
```

Answer (score 5):

Считываем файл и получаем текст

```
with open('pairs.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(text)  # "[1,2,3,4,5]"
```

Можно его распарсить как [json](/questions/tagged/json) через [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads), т.к. синтаксически он верный:

```
import json
items = json.loads(text)
print(items)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Или распарсить как тип [python](/questions/tagged/python) через [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
items = ast.literal_eval(text)
print(items)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Или парсим строку, составляя из нее список:

```
items = text[1:-1].split(',')
print(items)  # ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

items = list(map(int, text[1:-1].split(',')))
print(items)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

items = [int(x) for x in text[1:-1].split(',')]
print(items)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```