# Можно ли в python преобразовать строку в словарь?

Tags: python, dict

Из строчки:

```
string = '{"name":"Иван Иванов","ids":[1,2,3],"balance":12345}'
```

В словарь:

```
dict = {"name":"Иван Иванов","ids":[1,2,3],"balance":12345}
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(string)`.

Comment: Каков точный синтаксис записанного в этой строке? Это Python-литерал или, может, всё-таки JSON-объект?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1264444/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8c-python?rq=1

Comment: прежде чем писать вопрос не пробовали посмотреть тут? или просто прогуглить?....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да и очень легко! Вам просто надо выполнить следующую строку:

```py
data = eval('{"name":"Иван Иванов","ids":[1,2,3],"balance":12345}')
```

Функция `eval` просто выполняет код из строки. В данном случае мы просто инициализируем словарь.

Надеюсь, информация была полезна. Удачи!

Answer (score 5):

Можно с использованием json

```
import json

data_dict = json.loads('{"name":"Иван Иванов","ids":[1,2,3],"balance":12345}')
```