# python : Чтение txt файла построчно с преобразованием в словарь

Tags: python

есть txt файл со строками вида:

```
{'a' : '1', 'b' : 2, 'c': 'd'}
{'a' : '4', 'b' : 12, 'c': 'j'}
{'a' : '16', 'b' : 12, 'c': 'd'}
```

Знаю, как прочитать файл построчно, но не знаю, как прочитанную строку пребразовать в словарь?

Comment: `from ast import literal_eval; dict_ = literal_eval(line)`

Comment: еще через `json.loads` можно. только придется добавить `replace("'",'"')`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как безопасно превратить строку в словарь Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1264444/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8c-python)

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin в том вопросе про json, тут не json

Comment: @andreymal А ну да. Первый взгляд упал на название того вопроса :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
line = "{'a' : '1', 'b' : 2, 'c': 'd'}"
line = line.replace("'", "").replace("{", "").replace("}", "").split(',')


result_dict = dict()
for i in line:
    result_dict[i.split(':')[0].strip()] = i.split(':')[1].strip()
```

In `line` variable store your strings from .txt

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык

Comment: This works best! Thank you!

Comment: Если ответ подошёл, укажи его, пожалуйста, как "Правильный")